# PHP file upload with preset file name

Tags: php, file, upload

I was wondering if someone could help me figure this out. I want to be able to upload a picture to a users director with PHP, but I want it to change the default name to avatar.whatever. Here is the code I have so far which is just the w3schools version slightly modified:

```
<?php
session_start();

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["avatar"]["size"] < 100000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["avatar"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["avatar"]["error"] . "<br \>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["avatar"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["avatar"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["avatar"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    $home_dir = "users/" . $_SESSION["user"] . "/";

    if (file_exists($home_dir . $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["avatar"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"],$home_dir . $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

The form section works good and I would get rid of the if statement that checks if a file already exists and not output as much but can someone help me figure out how to set a pre-defined file name. The user would be able to select a picture file and then it will upload to their directory. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `move_uploaded_files()` function (at the very end of your code) accepts two parameters: the file's temporary location and name, and the desired location and name. Currently, you're doing this:

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"],$home_dir . $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]);
 echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
```

Which stores the file with the name `$_FILES["avatar"]["name"]` (the user's file name). Simply replace that with your desired name: `$home_dir . "the name i want.whatever"`.

Comment: Thanks! Worked great and great explaining.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"],$home_dir . $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]);
```

will rename the file with the second parameter:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"],"/path/to/image_predefined_name.jpg");
```

will save it with the name image_predefined_name.jpg.